# Issues with WMI

Tags: c#, wmi, wmi-query, comexception

I'm trying to build an application that can monitor an application on another computer on the network to ensure that it is running. I'm trying to use WMI to do that. I am able to access the server with wmimgmt.msc so it doesn't seem to be an issue of services not being enabled that are needed. Below is my code:

```
ConnectionOptions op = new ConnectionOptions();
op.Username = "domain.com\\Administrator";
op.Password = "Password";
ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope(@"\\SERVERNAME.Domain\root\cim2", op);
scope.Connect();
ManagementPath path = new ManagementPath("Win32_Service");
ManagementClass services = new ManagementClass(scope, path, null);

foreach (ManagementObject service in services.GetInstances())
{
    lv1.Items.Clear();
    if (service.GetPropertyValue("State").ToString().ToLower().Equals("running"))
    { // Do something }
        lv1.Items.Add(service.ToString());
    }
}
```

When this runs I get an InteropServices.COMException: `The RPC server is unavailable. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800706BA)` None of the fixes that I have seen online have helped. (ex: https://www.drivereasy.com/knowledge/rpc-server-is-unavailable-error-on-windows-10-fixed/) Any suggestions as to how to fix the code or another way to get what's running on the server remotely?

Comment: I assume you have checked that the RPC and RPC Endpoint Mapper services are running. Also verify whether the Firewall has a WMI rule enabled (also, try after having disabled the Firewall). Verify it with these settings: `op.EnablePrivileges = true; op.Authentication = AuthenticationLevel.PacketPrivacy; op.Impersonation = ImpersonationLevel.Identify; op.Password = "Password";op.Username = "Username"; op.Authority = "NTLMDOMAIN:domain.com";`

Comment: The two RCP services are running on both machines. I have tried using the above settings but the `.Authority` setting keeps giving me an 'Invalid Parameter' error. I have tried a few variations of the domain name without success.

Comment: If it's not a typo of sort, as the answer suggests (also, username is "Administrator" and \\ComputerName\ is just the name and can be the IP address of the machine), try, as `Impersonation`, `ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate` or the default `ImpersonationLevel.Unchanged`. Double check what you have written.

Comment: The 0x800706BA error is Firewall related (see: [WMI Troubleshooting and Tips](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692772.aspx)).  The Firewall rule should be (I can't verify right now) `netsh advfirewall firewall set rule group="Windows Remote Management" new enable=yes`. The Authority property depends on the network authentication handler. You can leave it blank and use `domain\Username` as user name.

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo,it has to be `root\cimv2`.

For future coding, make sure you are able to fetch the information using `wbemtest`, it will save you lots of time and effort.